# Display lines within {} in Python

Tags: python

I need to print the lines inside the `{}` of "`List A`" using Python. I'm reading out the lines and searching for the string `List A` but I am not sure how to display only the lines within the `{}`.

Example:

```
  List A
  {
    name,
    place,
    animal,
    thing
  }

 List B
 {
    Cat,
    Dog,
 }
```

Update: I tried the print(re.compile('List A\n\{\n(.*)\n\}', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
      .search(s).groups()[0]) mentioned but it did not work. Gave me the error group not found.

I tried to find the string "List B" but that dint work either. I have pasted my code below.

```
import sys
input_file = open(r'path/input.txt') 
Output_file = open('path/output.txt','w')
input_file_read = input_file.read()
for line in str(input_file_read):
    output_file.write(line)
    if line == "List B":
        next(line)
        print line
```

input_file_read is the input file open for read and output_file is the output file for writing the output.

Question:  Can anyone tell me why the if statement does not search the string?? and how I can search for the List B among many List?? I have only given a sample of the input file there are many List in that ~ 30 with the same format though. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: 1) read next line (after `List A`) and skip it, 2) read next line and if it is not `}` then print it else go to 4, 3) go back to 2, 4) the end.

Comment: The lines I have given above are in a file (input file) my script should read these lines and display the lines after the { and before the }

Comment: so each is on a separate line?

Comment: Yes. They are on separate lines

Answer (score 1):

A more generic example to handle any List name:

```
import re
s = ''  # Put your content into s
for match in re.finditer(r'List\s+(\w+)\s*\{(.*?)\}', s, re.DOTALL)
    print '-------New List--------'
    print 'Name of List:', m.group(1)
    print 'Content of List:', m.group(2)
```

Comment: This is not bad, but it fails on a text like "List B List A {…}". This is arguably probably not a real-life case, though, so no downvote. :) However, the loop is definitely not in a good style: it should simply be `for m in matches`.

Comment: You could fix the "List B List A {…}" problem by replacing `\w+` with `[^\n]+`, no?

Comment: @ EOL Awesome thanks to you guys!!! It worked... I replaced \w+ with [^\n]+ because previously it returned all the lists in file.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

s = """
List A
{
name,
place,
animal,
thing
}
"""

print(re.compile('List A\\n\\{\n(.*)\\n\\}', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
      .search(s).groups()[0])
```

Output:

```
name,
place,
animal,
thing
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but… This fails when there are more closing curly braces after "List A". Also, `MULTILINE` has no reason to be here. Also, compiling before searching is of no use. And finally, using raw strings would be easier. My answer is essentially the working and improved version of this otherwise good idea. :)

Answer (score -1):

It you start from a string `input_str` containing the text, then using a regular expression should be fast:

```
re.search(r'List A\n\s*\{\n(.*?)\n\s*\}', input_str, re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

gives

```
name,
place,
animal,
thing
```

You can see the structure of your text in the regular expression (`\n` is a newline). The `.*?\n\}` matches everything (`.*` means any number of arbitrary characters, including newlines, thanks to the `DOTALL`)… but stop *as soon as* it encounters the *first* closing brace (thanks to the `?`). The `\s*` represent a varying number of spaces (because the braces in the question are not always exactly at line starts).

If you start from a file, like in your example, then the solution above can be used (with `input_str = input_file.read()`), but it's a bit of a waste (since this unnecessarily reads past the List A group). So, another possibility is to read the file line by line and start and stop collecting data on the fly (with a finite automaton). However, this does not seem convenient (unless you use an external parsing module). So, if your file is not too big, I think that the regular expression solution above is appropriate.